# Postfix: /usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory - why?

Tags: debian, postfix

I am trying to get postfix working, and when I test it using `mail user` I enter the subject, message, ect and get the following error:

```
mail: /usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed
```

Why is it talking about sendmail?  I deleted that a long time ago and am using postfix.  Is it still hanging around somewhere and the mail command thinks it should be using sendmail?

Comment: Could you post the output from `postconf –n`

Comment: I get: postconf: warning: ???n: unknown parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `postfix` package on Debian actually includes an `/usr/sbin/sendmail` executable that functions as a compatibility interface (see `man sendmail` when `postfix` is installed).

Check `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail*` in case it was renamed or reinstall the `postfix` package so you get the wrapper in place.

Comment: I try to reinstall, and I get an error talking about sendmail: Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Should I just install sendmail-base on its own?

Comment: You shouldn't install any part of sendmail really, just postfix. Please post the output of `dpkg-query -L postfix | grep sendmail`.

Comment: Thanks, running that gives me: /usr/sbin/sendmail
/usr/share/man/man1/sendmail.1.gz
/usr/lib/sendmail

Comment: And yet `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` returns "No such file or directory"? I'd say your install is botched in some specific way that also causes reinstall to malfunction - try backing up all config files by hand, then `apt-get remove --purge postfix` (do back up first!) and finally `apt-get install postfix`.

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try.

Comment: Ok I was able to reinstall it.  But again trying to a simple mail user doesn't work: /usr/bin/mail: No such file or directory

Comment: When testing it from php I get no email and see nothing in the logs...

Comment: You wrote `/usr/bin/mail` this time around - did you mean it? In that case `apt-get install bsd-mailx`.

Comment: $type sendmail
`sendmail is /usr/sbin/sendmail`
This is not a **wrapper**; it is the postfix sendmail executable.

Comment: @adaptr - the man page describes it as a *compatibility interface*. By wrapper I meant that it's not a real, parallel sendmail implementation, but something that "translates" some/most sendmail commands for postfix.

Comment: You said `The postfix package on Debian actually includes a wrapper in the form of /usr/sbin/sendmail for compatibility reasons.`
Well, 1. it is not a wrapper, but an executable that submits mail, 2. it is not part of any debian-specific package, but a postfix source executable, and 3. it has nothing to do wtih compatibility in and of itself; it merely offers an interface that is compatible with the sendmail system, so administrators can replace sendmail with postfix without recoding all the scripts that use sendmail.

Comment: I modified my answer to remove the infringing word, thanks for the heads up. By the way, I found this humorous: `3. it has nothing to do wtih compatibility in and of itself; it merely offers an interface that is compatible with the sendmail system`. Thanks for clearing that up, mate! :)

Comment: I meant that the reason for the existence of the postfix sendmail(1) executable is not, in and of itself, compatibility - except insofar as it is also *called* "sendmail", to provide said compatibility with existing systems. The functionality it offers is local mail submission - something that is not inherently unique to the sendmail MTA :)

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have /usr/sbin/sendmail, check if after installing postfix package, you have:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
```

If you do, simply make a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Answer (score 1):

The postfix installation is probably broken.
Try this:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall postfix
```

Comment: Did this, and it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, and the following cmd fix it,

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation in linux machines at my work place where accidently emptied the mailq (mta-mail) file with echo > instead of postgress -d all commands and my it was a scare . Never going to touch binaries like that :)

SO in the system usually i seen they use many softlinks to link mailq, sendmai, to finally on the sendmail.postfix

I got a solution by installing sendmail package again.

im on Centos so
yum install sendmail
THis site helped me out with steps manual
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/oxid/troubleshooting/send-mail/

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 12 admin user I had to add `/usr/sbin` to it's path:

Add this to the bottom of `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -d "/usr/sbin" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"
fi
```

$ `source ~/.profile` # or logout / login.